# Error in launching virtual machines in VirtualBox (windows 7)?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine

All worked fine before this but now when ever I try to launch a vm I get this error:

```
ntdll.dll not found in child process (rc=-610)

Please try reinstalling VirtualBox.

where: supR3HardNtChildFindNtdll what: 5 VERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND (-610) - Module not found.
```

and the following log file :

```
2490.18a4: Log file opened: 5.1.23r115370 g_hStartupLog=0000000000000014 g_uNtVerCombined=0x611db110
2490.18a4: \SystemRoot\System32\ntdll.dll:
2490.18a4:     CreationTime:    2017-05-10T17:56:47.649399100Z
2490.18a4:     LastWriteTime:   2017-04-28T01:11:49.878278200Z
2490.18a4:     ChangeTime:      2017-05-11T01:54:11.268235100Z
2490.18a4:     FileAttributes:  0x20
2490.18a4:     Size:            0x1a7100
2490.18a4:     NT Headers:      0xe0
2490.18a4:     Timestamp:       0x590296ce
2490.18a4:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
2490.18a4:     Timestamp:       0x590296ce
2490.18a4:     Image Version:   6.1
2490.18a4:     SizeOfImage:     0x1aa000 (1744896)
2490.18a4:     Resource Dir:    0x14e000 LB 0x5a028
2490.18a4:     [Version info resource found at 0xd8! (ID/Name: 0x1; SubID/SubName: 0x409)]
2490.18a4:     [Raw version resource data: 0x14e0f0 LB 0x380, codepage 0x0 (reserved 0x0)]
2490.18a4:     ProductName:     Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
2490.18a4:     ProductVersion:  6.1.7601.23796
2490.18a4:     FileVersion:     6.1.7601.23796 (win7sp1_ldr.170427-1518)
2490.18a4:     FileDescription: NT Layer DLL
2490.18a4: \SystemRoot\System32\kernel32.dll:
2490.18a4:     CreationTime:    2017-05-10T17:56:46.117306500Z
2490.18a4:     LastWriteTime:   2017-04-28T01:10:02.307000000Z
2490.18a4:     ChangeTime:      2017-05-11T01:54:14.903041500Z
2490.18a4:     FileAttributes:  0x20
2490.18a4:     Size:            0x11c000
2490.18a4:     NT Headers:      0xe0
2490.18a4:     Timestamp:       0x59029713
2490.18a4:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
2490.18a4:     Timestamp:       0x59029713
2490.18a4:     Image Version:   6.1
2490.18a4:     SizeOfImage:     0x11f000 (1175552)
2490.18a4:     Resource Dir:    0x116000 LB 0x528
2490.18a4:     [Version info resource found at 0x90! (ID/Name: 0x1; SubID/SubName: 0x409)]
2490.18a4:     [Raw version resource data: 0x1160b0 LB 0x3a4, codepage 0x0 (reserved 0x0)]
2490.18a4:     ProductName:     Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
2490.18a4:     ProductVersion:  6.1.7601.23796
2490.18a4:     FileVersion:     6.1.7601.23796 (win7sp1_ldr.170427-1518)
2490.18a4:     FileDescription: Windows NT BASE API Client DLL
2490.18a4: \SystemRoot\System32\KernelBase.dll:
2490.18a4:     CreationTime:    2017-05-10T17:56:44.845213300Z
2490.18a4:     LastWriteTime:   2017-04-28T01:10:02.307000000Z
2490.18a4:     ChangeTime:      2017-05-11T01:54:14.871841400Z
2490.18a4:     FileAttributes:  0x20
2490.18a4:     Size:            0x66800
2490.18a4:     NT Headers:      0xe8
2490.18a4:     Timestamp:       0x59029714
2490.18a4:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
2490.18a4:     Timestamp:       0x59029714
2490.18a4:     Image Version:   6.1
2490.18a4:     SizeOfImage:     0x6a000 (434176)
2490.18a4:     Resource Dir:    0x68000 LB 0x530
2490.18a4:     [Version info resource found at 0x90! (ID/Name: 0x1; SubID/SubName: 0x409)]
2490.18a4:     [Raw version resource data: 0x680b0 LB 0x3ac, codepage 0x0 (reserved 0x0)]
2490.18a4:     ProductName:     Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
2490.18a4:     ProductVersion:  6.1.7601.23796
2490.18a4:     FileVersion:     6.1.7601.23796 (win7sp1_ldr.170427-1518)
2490.18a4:     FileDescription: Windows NT BASE API Client DLL
2490.18a4: \SystemRoot\System32\apisetschema.dll:
2490.18a4:     CreationTime:    2017-05-10T17:56:43.061097800Z
2490.18a4:     LastWriteTime:   2017-04-28T01:09:58.126000000Z
2490.18a4:     ChangeTime:      2017-05-11T01:54:11.081034800Z
2490.18a4:     FileAttributes:  0x20
2490.18a4:     Size:            0x1a00
2490.18a4:     NT Headers:      0xc0
2490.18a4:     Timestamp:       0x590296af
2490.18a4:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
2490.18a4:     Timestamp:       0x590296af
2490.18a4:     Image Version:   6.1
2490.18a4:     SizeOfImage:     0x50000 (327680)
2490.18a4:     Resource Dir:    0x30000 LB 0x3f8
2490.18a4:     [Version info resource found at 0x48! (ID/Name: 0x1; SubID/SubName: 0x409)]
2490.18a4:     [Raw version resource data: 0x30060 LB 0x398, codepage 0x0 (reserved 0x0)]
2490.18a4:     ProductName:     Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
2490.18a4:     ProductVersion:  6.1.7601.23796
2490.18a4:     FileVersion:     6.1.7601.23796 (win7sp1_ldr.170427-1518)
2490.18a4:     FileDescription: ApiSet Schema DLL
2490.18a4: Found driver klkbdflt (0x40)
2490.18a4: Found driver klmouflt (0x40)
2490.18a4: Found driver KLIM6 (0x40)
2490.18a4: Found driver kl1 (0x40)
2490.18a4: Found driver kneps (0x40)
2490.18a4: Found driver kltdi (0x40)
2490.18a4: supR3HardenedWinFindAdversaries: 0xc0
2490.18a4: \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\kl1.sys:
2490.18a4:     CreationTime:    2012-04-13T11:54:06.000000000Z
2490.18a4:     LastWriteTime:   2012-04-13T11:54:06.000000000Z
2490.18a4:     ChangeTime:      2017-04-24T22:17:46.074384800Z
2490.18a4:     FileAttributes:  0x20
2490.18a4:     Size:            0x6ff30
2490.18a4:     NT Headers:      0xe0
2490.18a4:     Timestamp:       0x4f87f79f
2490.18a4:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
2490.18a4:     Timestamp:       0x4f87f79f
2490.18a4:     Image Version:   0.0
2490.18a4:     SizeOfImage:     0x75e000 (7725056)
2490.18a4:     Resource Dir:    0x75c000 LB 0x448
2490.18a4:     [Version info resource found at 0x48! (ID/Name: 0x1; SubID/SubName: 0x419)]
2490.18a4:     [Raw version resource data: 0x75c060 LB 0x3e8, codepage 0x0 (reserved 0x0)]
2490.18a4:     ProductName:     Kaspersky Anti-Virus
2490.18a4:     ProductVersion:  6.0.1.892
2490.18a4:     FileVersion:     6.8.0.15
2490.18a4:     FileDescription: Kaspersky Unified Driver
2490.18a4: \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\klflt.sys:
2490.18a4:     CreationTime:    2017-04-24T22:16:32.951202400Z
2490.18a4:     LastWriteTime:   2012-05-29T13:55:42.000000000Z
2490.18a4:     ChangeTime:      2017-04-24T22:16:43.220789800Z
2490.18a4:     FileAttributes:  0x20
2490.18a4:     Size:            0x14d58
2490.18a4:     NT Headers:      0xf0
2490.18a4:     Timestamp:       0x4fc4aefa
2490.18a4:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
2490.18a4:     Timestamp:       0x4fc4aefa
2490.18a4:     Image Version:   6.1
2490.18a4:     SizeOfImage:     0x20000 (131072)
2490.18a4:     Resource Dir:    0x1e000 LB 0x388
2490.18a4:     [Version info resource found at 0x48! (ID/Name: 0x1; SubID/SubName: 0x409)]
2490.18a4:     [Raw version resource data: 0x1e060 LB 0x328, codepage 0x0 (reserved 0x0)]
2490.18a4:     ProductName:     Kaspersky™ Anti-Virus ®
2490.18a4:     ProductVersion:  1.0.0.158
2490.18a4:     FileVersion:     1.0.0.158 built by: WinDDK
2490.18a4:     FileDescription: Filter Core [fre_wlh_amd64]
2490.18a4: \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\klif.sys:
2490.18a4:     CreationTime:    2017-04-24T22:16:32.883198500Z
2490.18a4:     LastWriteTime:   2012-05-29T13:55:40.000000000Z
2490.18a4:     ChangeTime:      2017-04-24T22:16:43.211789300Z
2490.18a4:     FileAttributes:  0x20
2490.18a4:     Size:            0x9c558
2490.18a4:     NT Headers:      0x100
2490.18a4:     Timestamp:       0x4fc4b831
2490.18a4:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
2490.18a4:     Timestamp:       0x4fc4b831
2490.18a4:     Image Version:   6.1
2490.18a4:     SizeOfImage:     0xa8000 (688128)
2490.18a4:     Resource Dir:    0xa6000 LB 0x398
2490.18a4:     [Version info resource found at 0x48! (ID/Name: 0x1; SubID/SubName: 0x409)]
2490.18a4:     [Raw version resource data: 0xa6060 LB 0x338, codepage 0x0 (reserved 0x0)]
2490.18a4:     ProductName:     Kaspersky™ Anti-Virus ®
2490.18a4:     ProductVersion:  8.10.0.537
2490.18a4:     FileVersion:     8.10.0.537 built by: WinDDK
2490.18a4:     FileDescription: Klif Mini-Filter [fre_wlh_amd64]
2490.18a4: \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\klim6.sys:
2490.18a4:     CreationTime:    2012-03-27T16:34:24.000000000Z
2490.18a4:     LastWriteTime:   2012-03-27T16:34:24.000000000Z
2490.18a4:     ChangeTime:      2017-04-24T22:17:39.956034800Z
2490.18a4:     FileAttributes:  0x20
2490.18a4:     Size:            0x7530
2490.18a4:     NT Headers:      0xe0
2490.18a4:     Timestamp:       0x4f71cfe1
2490.18a4:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
2490.18a4:     Timestamp:       0x4f71cfe1
2490.18a4:     Image Version:   0.0
2490.18a4:     SizeOfImage:     0xa000 (40960)
2490.18a4:     Resource Dir:    0x8000 LB 0x470
2490.18a4:     [Version info resource found at 0x48! (ID/Name: 0x1; SubID/SubName: 0x419)]
2490.18a4:     [Raw version resource data: 0x8060 LB 0x410, codepage 0x0 (reserved 0x0)]
2490.18a4:     ProductName:     Kaspersky Anti-Virus
2490.18a4:     ProductVersion:  6.0.1.862
2490.18a4:     FileVersion:     8.0.0.29
2490.18a4:     FileDescription: Kaspersky Lab Intermediate Network Driver
2490.18a4: \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\klkbdflt.sys:
2490.18a4:     CreationTime:    2012-05-25T17:38:48.000000000Z
2490.18a4:     LastWriteTime:   2012-05-25T17:38:48.000000000Z
2490.18a4:     ChangeTime:      2017-04-24T22:17:48.771539100Z
2490.18a4:     FileAttributes:  0x20
2490.18a4:     Size:            0x7158
2490.18a4:     NT Headers:      0xf8
2490.18a4:     Timestamp:       0x4fbfa772
2490.18a4:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
2490.18a4:     Timestamp:       0x4fbfa772
2490.18a4:     Image Version:   6.1
2490.18a4:     SizeOfImage:     0xb000 (45056)
2490.18a4:     Resource Dir:    0x9000 LB 0x3c0
2490.18a4:     [Version info resource found at 0x48! (ID/Name: 0x1; SubID/SubName: 0x409)]
2490.18a4:     [Raw version resource data: 0x9060 LB 0x360, codepage 0x0 (reserved 0x0)]
2490.18a4:     ProductName:     Kaspersky™ Anti-Virus ®
2490.18a4:     ProductVersion:  8.10.0.21
2490.18a4:     FileVersion:     8.10.0.21 built by: WinDDK
2490.18a4:     FileDescription: KLKBDFLT Keyboard Device Filter [fre_wlh_amd64]
2490.18a4: \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\klmouflt.sys:
2490.18a4:     CreationTime:    2012-05-25T17:30:34.000000000Z
2490.18a4:     LastWriteTime:   2012-05-25T17:30:34.000000000Z
2490.18a4:     ChangeTime:      2017-04-24T22:17:46.803426500Z
2490.18a4:     FileAttributes:  0x20
2490.18a4:     Size:            0x6d58
2490.18a4:     NT Headers:      0xf0
2490.18a4:     Timestamp:       0x4fbfa587
2490.18a4:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
2490.18a4:     Timestamp:       0x4fbfa587
2490.18a4:     Image Version:   6.1
2490.18a4:     SizeOfImage:     0xc000 (49152)
2490.18a4:     Resource Dir:    0xa000 LB 0x3c0
2490.18a4:     [Version info resource found at 0x48! (ID/Name: 0x1; SubID/SubName: 0x409)]
2490.18a4:     [Raw version resource data: 0xa060 LB 0x35c, codepage 0x0 (reserved 0x0)]
2490.18a4:     ProductName:     Kaspersky™ Anti-Virus ®
2490.18a4:     ProductVersion:  8.10.0.22
2490.18a4:     FileVersion:     8.10.0.22 built by: WinDDK
2490.18a4:     FileDescription: KLMOUFLT Mouse Device Filter [fre_wlh_amd64]
2490.18a4: \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\kltdi.sys:
2490.18a4:     CreationTime:    2012-05-12T15:13:34.000000000Z
2490.18a4:     LastWriteTime:   2012-05-12T15:13:34.000000000Z
2490.18a4:     ChangeTime:      2017-04-24T22:17:50.697649200Z
2490.18a4:     FileAttributes:  0x20
2490.18a4:     Size:            0xd330
2490.18a4:     NT Headers:      0x100
2490.18a4:     Timestamp:       0x4fae61f1
2490.18a4:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
2490.18a4:     Timestamp:       0x4fae61f1
2490.18a4:     Image Version:   6.1
2490.18a4:     SizeOfImage:     0x10000 (65536)
2490.18a4:     Resource Dir:    0xe000 LB 0x388
2490.18a4:     [Version info resource found at 0x48! (ID/Name: 0x1; SubID/SubName: 0x409)]
2490.18a4:     [Raw version resource data: 0xe060 LB 0x324, codepage 0x0 (reserved 0x0)]
2490.18a4:     ProductName:     Kaspersky™ Anti-Virus ®
2490.18a4:     ProductVersion:  1.0.0.90
2490.18a4:     FileVersion:     1.0.0.90 built by: WinDDK
2490.18a4:     FileDescription: Network filtering component
2490.18a4: \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\kneps.sys:
2490.18a4:     CreationTime:    2012-05-24T09:34:46.000000000Z
2490.18a4:     LastWriteTime:   2012-05-24T09:34:46.000000000Z
2490.18a4:     ChangeTime:      2017-04-24T22:17:51.359687100Z
2490.18a4:     FileAttributes:  0x20
2490.18a4:     Size:            0x2a358
2490.18a4:     NT Headers:      0x120
2490.18a4:     Timestamp:       0x4fbde44c
2490.18a4:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
2490.18a4:     Timestamp:       0x4fbde44c
2490.18a4:     Image Version:   6.1
2490.18a4:     SizeOfImage:     0x2c000 (180224)
2490.18a4:     Resource Dir:    0x2a000 LB 0x368
2490.18a4:     [Version info resource found at 0x48! (ID/Name: 0x1; SubID/SubName: 0x409)]
2490.18a4:     [Raw version resource data: 0x2a060 LB 0x308, codepage 0x0 (reserved 0x0)]
2490.18a4:     ProductName:     Kaspersky™ Anti-Virus ®
2490.18a4:     ProductVersion:  5.0.0.108
2490.18a4:     FileVersion:     5.0.0.108 built by: WinDDK
2490.18a4:     FileDescription: KNEPS Power
2490.18a4: \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\MBAMSwissArmy.sys:
2490.18a4:     CreationTime:    2017-05-01T23:30:33.300583900Z
2490.18a4:     LastWriteTime:   2017-05-11T02:01:58.127579700Z
2490.18a4:     ChangeTime:      2017-05-11T02:01:58.127579700Z
2490.18a4:     FileAttributes:  0x20
2490.18a4:     Size:            0x3d7b8
2490.18a4:     NT Headers:      0x100
2490.18a4:     Timestamp:       0x58c98f59
2490.18a4:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
2490.18a4:     Timestamp:       0x58c98f59
2490.18a4:     Image Version:   6.3
2490.18a4:     SizeOfImage:     0x3f000 (258048)
2490.18a4:     Resource Dir:    0x3d000 LB 0x3b8
2490.18a4:     [Version info resource found at 0x48! (ID/Name: 0x1; SubID/SubName: 0x409)]
2490.18a4:     [Raw version resource data: 0x3d060 LB 0x358, codepage 0x0 (reserved 0x0)]
2490.18a4:     ProductName:     Malwarebytes SwissArmy
2490.18a4:     ProductVersion:  4.2.0.112
2490.18a4:     FileVersion:     4.2.0.112
2490.18a4:     FileDescription: Malwarebytes SwissArmy
2490.18a4: supR3HardenedWinInitAppBin(0x0): '\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox'
2490.18a4: Calling main()
2490.18a4: SUPR3HardenedMain: pszProgName=VirtualBox fFlags=0x2
2490.18a4: supR3HardenedWinInitAppBin(0x2): '\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox'
2490.18a4: SUPR3HardenedMain: Respawn #1
2490.18a4: System32:  \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32
2490.18a4: WinSxS:    \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\winsxs
2490.18a4: KnownDllPath: C:\Windows\system32
2490.18a4: '\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe' has no imports
2490.18a4: supHardenedWinVerifyImageByHandle: -> 0 (\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe)
2490.18a4: supR3HardNtEnableThreadCreation:
2490.18a4: supR3HardNtDisableThreadCreation: pvLdrInitThunk=0000000076e0a360 pvNtTerminateThread=0000000076e2c260
2490.18a4: supR3HardenedWinDoReSpawn(1): New child 2668.2118 [kernel32].
2490.18a4: supR3HardNtChildGatherData: PebBaseAddress=000007fffffdd000 cbPeb=0x380
2490.18a4: Error (rc=-610):
2490.18a4: ntdll.dll not found in child process.
2490.18a4: Error -610 in supR3HardNtChildFindNtdll! (enmWhat=5)
2490.18a4: ntdll.dll not found in child process.
2490.18a4: supR3HardNtEnableThreadCreation:
```

I tryed reinstalling VB and I VB test build, but with no success. I am using 64 bit windows 7 VB version : Version 5.1.23 r115370 (Qt5.6.2)

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? I am having this exact same problem, on the same versions.